# MySQL username and password check

Tags: mysql, database, authentication

I want to create a simple (non-secure) login-check from mysql database, where I have a table which has Login_name and Password fields. However, my system logs in if the Login_name is right no matter what password the user inserts. How do I fix the system to check that both match the user? My SQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_getUserAccount`(IN username VARCHAR(255), IN password VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
select Name, Access_level_group, ID
from User_accounts
where Password = password
AND Login_name = username;
END
$$
```

Comment: Password = password. Are you sure that your system is case sensitive? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Yes, that's the mistake, I'm beginning with mysql, so I didn't realise that, although I knew it's case insensitive. This is one of the mistakes you just become blind yourself, no matter how many times you try to look for the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe MySQL is case insensitive, so Password = password is always true. You need to clarify that you are wanting to check User_accounts.Password, instead of just the password parameter. So either change the name of your IN parameter, or replace Password with User_accounts.Password.

Comment: No, I think it is case-sensitive. But anyways, you must prefix it _ to stop any discrepancy.

Comment: I changed IN parameter 'password' to 'passwd', and accordingly Password = passwd works now.